# Are Puranas of divine origin?

Tags: puranas

Do the Puranas have divine origin or inspiration,like vedas and Bhagavad Gita. And can we take puranas as literaler truth.

Comment: Puranas are Smriti, not Sruti. By definition only sruti is of divine origin. Search these 2 terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are Puranas of divine origin?

Yes, because they are authored by gods and rishis. The [Vishnu Purana](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp036.htm) for example comes from Lord Brahma:

> I will relate to you that which was originally imparted by the great father of all (Brahmá), in answer to the questions of Daksha and other venerable sages, and repeated by them to Purukutsa, a king who reigned on the banks of the Narmadá. It was next related by him to Sáraswata, and by Sáraswata to me.