# The origin of the Puranas

Tags: vedas, puranas, tantra

I am interested to study the origin of the Puranas and the relationship they share with the Vedas. Any incident, for example, the origin of Maa Ganga on earth, has been variously described in the Puranas. This gives some western-educated self-claimed historians and self-claimed "orientalists" the scope of presenting the Puranas as "stories". When I hear their assertion about the Puranas, I feel very pained. I don't know how to challenge their narrative. Please advise on the way to more serious academic (and Tantric) studies about the Puranas so that I can challenge their narrative.

Comment: There are two types of stories - puranic and itihaasic. Itihaasic ones are considered true happenings of the history and puranic are usually made up stories to make the audience understand the underlying concepts of upanishads. Puranas aren't usually considered higher texts as they have a lot of personal opinion and are composed likely much later.

Comment: question is about "origin of the Puranas and the relationship they share with the Vedas", not about which one is higher or lower.

Comment: @brahmāstra I see. I was talking about the stories of Puranas which the OP is concerned about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Puranas of divine origin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/are-puranas-of-divine-origin)

Answer (score 1):

Purans are smriti. Vyas is more likely a tittle not a name.
It's false to say that Ved-Vyas himself wrote Purans.

Vishnu Purana mentions that Vyasa entrusted his Puranasamhita to his disciple Lomaharshana, who in turn imparted it to his disciples, 3 of whom compiled their own samhitas. These 3, together with Lomaharshana's,comprise the Mulasamhita,from which the later 18 Main-Puranas were derived.

Means Purans were written by many sages. It explains there contradictory nature. Yea its true that Purana contradict each other at certain places. Either that's a product of interpolation or it was written like this (some says Kalpa Bheda).

> शब्द इतिचेन्नातः प्रभवात्प्रत्यक्षानुमानाभ्याम्
>
> If it be said that a contradiction will result in regard to Word
> (Vedas), we say that it is not so because the origination of
> everything is from perception and inference. Adi Shankara's
> commentary:
>
> "Perception means Sruti; for its validity it is not dependent on
> anything else; inference is Smriti".
>
> —Brahma sutra 1.3.28

Sruti-Vedas,

If you want to read Purans then read it through Upanishads.
Reason- If you directly read the Purans, then you will end up in void because Purans presents the same story from many perspective.

Like Shiv-Linga. If you try to find answer about the formation of Shiv-linga then you find many stories that too in a single Puran, maybe some are result of interpolation but it is as it is.
This thing is very confusing but if you go through Purans via Upanishad, then you will not only able to filter it part but will also get the true essense of the Purans.

Addition.

During Vedic yajñas which lasted several days, months or even years, the participants would pass the time between the daily sessions, by narrating legends of old these are what “Purāṇa” mentioned in the Upaṇiṣads refers to. Purāṇa simply means “ancient stories”

Answer (score -1):

**Origin of the purANas and their relationship with vedas** is described in [***gopatha brAhmaNa***](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in:8443/jspui/handle/10603/151631) :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other vedas mention ***"fifth veda" as relationship of purANas with vedas*** :

> **chandogya-upanishad** :
>
> *नाम वा ऋग्वेदो यजुर्वेदः सामवेद आथर्वणश्चतुर्थ **इतिहासपुराणः पञ्चमो वेदानां वेदः** पित्र्यो राशिर्दैवो निधिर्वाकोवाक्यमेकायनं देवविद्या
> ब्रह्मविद्या भूतविद्या क्षत्रविद्या नक्षत्रविद्या सर्पदेवजनविद्या
> नामैवैतन्नामोपास्स्वेति ॥ ७.१.४ ॥*
>
> Name is the Ṛg Veda, the Yajur Veda, the Sāma Veda, and the fourth—the
> Atharva Veda; then the **fifth—history and the Purāṇas**; also,
> grammar, funeral rites, mathematics, the science of omens, the science
> of underground resources, logic, moral science, astrology, Vedic
> knowledge, the science of the elements, archery, astronomy, the
> science relating to snakes, plus music, dance, and other fine arts.
> These are only names. Worship name.
>
> **BRHAD-ARANYAKA UPANISAD 2.4.10** :
>
> *asya mahato bhutasya nihsvasitam etad yad rg-vedo yajur-vedah sama vedo’tharvangirasa itihasah **puranam** ityadina*
>
> *“O Maitreya, the Rg, Yajur, Sama and Atharva Vedas as well as Itihasas and the **Puranas all manifest from the breathing of the
> Lord**.”*
>
> **Atharva Veda 15.6.10–12** :
>
> *SA BRHATIM DISAM ANU VYACALAT TAM ITIHASAS CA **PURANAM** CA GATHAS CA ITIHASASYA CA SA VAI PURANASYA CA GATHANAM CA NARASAMSINAM CA
> PRIYAM DHAMA BHAVATI YA EVAM VEDA*
>
> *“He approached the brhati meter, and thus the Itihasas, **Puranas**, Gathas and Narasamsis became favorable to him. One who knows this
> verily becomes the beloved abode of the Itihasas, Puranas, Gathas and
> Narasamsis.”*