# Who are BrahmaKshatriya?

Tags: brahmins, varna, kshatriya

Who are Brahma Khatriyas? What is there varna Brahmin or Kshatriya? Is such varna mentioned in Shastras? Should they use Sharma or Varma in Abhivadan or Sankalpa mantras?
Are they eligible for both purohit karmas like teaching Vedas (allowed only for Brahmins) and royal duties like Rajasuya(allowed only for Kshatriyas)?

Comment: I know about the Bhumihar Brahmins but not detail so far.

Comment: As far I know Bhumihars are considered of the Brahmin Varna.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Puranas of divine origin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/are-puranas-of-divine-origin)

Comment: The that does not answer my question

Comment: There is no mention of brahmakshatriyas as a distinct caste group in text. The short-lived Sena dynasty which came to rule Bengal & is renowned for its efforts to reestablish Hindu orthodoxy in a land which was the last state to have Buddhism as its official religion before its conquest by Turkish Muslims, recorded themselves as brahmakshatriyas or brahmanas who had taken up the roles of a warrior who immigrated from South India during Rajendra I Chola's invasion of Bengal. Manusmriti also authorised brahmanas to take up the occupation of kshatriyas in times of distress.

Comment: The claim of Bhumihar brahmanas of being brahmakshatriyas is null-&-void, because they were simply landlords, not warriors per se. This claim was mostly likely made to perpetuate the myth of Bhumihar brahmanas being a superior caste compared to landless brahmanas.

Comment: Such instances of the rich forming their own caste to separate themselves from the poor aren't new. In Bengali Hindu society, traders of sesame oil (which had both secular & religious use) claimed to be a separate caste superior to the oil-trader caste. In Axomiya Hindu society, a section of Domes (smashana workers) who grew rich by trading activities are now classified as a separate caste by the name of Brittial Bania (meaning  Bania by profession as opposed to being Bania by caste).